# Why can't I declare a struct variable inside a lambda in c++0x?

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, c++11

Here's the code.

```
#include<struct.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>
using namespace std;

void LambdaTest(const function <struct dummy (void)>& f)
    {
    struct dummy test = f();
    cout<<test.a<<endl;
    }

int main()
    {
    int val = 5;
    struct dummy dum;

    auto func = [val](void) -> struct dummy
                        {
                        dummy temp;
                        temp.a = val;
                        return temp;
                        };

    LambdaTest(func);
    return 0;
    }
```

The file struct.h is very simple.

```
struct dummy
    {
    int a;
    };
```

GCC complains that

> lambda_struct.cpp:19:38: error: field ‘temp’ has incomplete type

Is this allowed? If yes, then how do I fix it? If not, then why not?

**EDIT:**

The return type bug in the code (discovered by others) has now been fixed.

**SOLUTION:**

The problem is that C++0x standard allows definition to a new struct (and a class too, presumably) in the *return type* of a lambda definition itself. So if struct keyword is present in the return type, the compiler will think that it is a new type and begin to complain.

The fixed code is

```
#include<struct.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>
using namespace std;

void LambdaTest(const function <struct dummy (void)>& f)
    {
    struct dummy test = f();
    cout<<test.a<<endl;
    }

int main()
    {
    int val = 5;
    struct dummy dum;

    auto func = [val](void) -> dummy
                        {
                        dummy temp;
                        temp.a = val;
                        return temp;
                        };

    LambdaTest(func);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting errors that your lambda doesn't return a value in MSVC++. `anonymous namespace'::<lambda0>::operator()' : must return a value. Once I fixed that it compiled and outputted 5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that GCC incorrectly thinks you're declaring a new struct type on the trailing return, and it declares a field of an incomplete type that is the same type GCC thinks you're declaring.

It also complains that

> error: 'temp' does not name a type

on the line with the assignment, because it is expecting a member declaration, not a statement.

Changing to:

```
auto func = [val](void) -> dummy
                        {
                            struct dummy temp;
                            temp.a = val;
                            return temp;
                        };
```

Will work.

Also, beware that not returning a value from a function will probably lead you into the realm of undefined behaviour.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You can't define a struct in a trailing return type, this was just a g++ bug.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you take away the `struct` part and just define the variable normally? You know, just:

```
dummy temp;
```

Also, try getting rid of the other superfluous `struct` in the lambda return value. Speaking of which, you need to actually *return* `temp` for it to compile.

Comment: Surprisingly, GCC (ideone) didn't even emit a warning about the missing return statement in the lambda. It happily prints out garbage within `LambdaTest()`

Answer (score 0):

In C++, unlike C, structures are not placed in a separate namespace, so you don't have to use the keyword `struct` in every declaration. Also, there is an error in your code, the lambda needs to return an instance of type `dummy`. The following compiles and runs as expected

```
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>
using namespace std;

struct dummy
    {
    int a;
    };

void LambdaTest(const function <dummy (void)>& f)
    {
    dummy test = f();
    cout<<test.a<<endl;
    }

int main()
    {
    int val = 5;
    dummy dum;

    auto func = [val](void) -> dummy
                        {
                        dummy temp;
                        temp.a = val;
                        return temp; // return the temp struct
                        };

    LambdaTest(func);
    return 0;
    }
```

Output:

> 5